# Apache "can't locate API module structure" with php73

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, lamp, php7, arch-linux

newbie here. I was working on installing a LAMP environment on Manjaro for testing, trying to use older versions to match the production environment I have to work with (PHP 7.3, MySQL 5.6; got them from the AUR) when I had a freeze and was forced to hard reboot; since then, I've been having a weird error with Apache ; the service now refuses to start.

When I start the service with `sudo systemctl start httpd`, I don't get an error, but when I use `sudo systemctl status httpd` to check its status after that, I see this :

```
● httpd.service - Apache Web Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-05-27 09:34:31 CEST; 7s ago
    Process: 82377 ExecStart=/usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 82377 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mai 27 09:34:31 gregoire-x751lx systemd[1]: Started Apache Web Server.
mai 27 09:34:31 gregoire-x751lx httpd[82377]: httpd: Syntax error on line 190 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php73_module' in file /etc/httpd/modules/libphp73.so: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp73.so: undefined symbol: php73_module
mai 27 09:34:31 gregoire-x751lx systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mai 27 09:34:31 gregoire-x751lx systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Line 190 and 191 of httpd.conf :

```
LoadModule php73_module modules/libphp73.so
AddHandler php73-script .php
```

`libphp73.so` exists in the correct location and I didn't have this error until the crash, so I tried reinstalling the php73, php73-apache and phpmyadmin packages using yay, thinking something must have changed that file somehow. Didn't change anything.

Please, what else should I try ? I'm really new to Linux and very inexperienced in server management in general, so I'm not sure what other info I should be giving ; I'll do my best to answer whatever is needed.

Answer (score 2):

A kind redditor solved my issue ! I changed `php73_module` to `php7_module` and it worked !

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp73.so
```